# The decay rate of a degenerate heat equation in torus $\mathbb{T}^2$

Tags: inequalities, parabolic-pde, heat-equation

Consider the degenerate heat equation on torus $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(x,t)= \left( \sin^2(\pi x_1) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x_2} + \sin^2(\pi x_2) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x_1} \right) u(x,t) ,$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{T}^2,t>0.$ We always assume that $\int_{\mathbb{T}^d} u(x,0) d x=0,$ so the mean of the solution $u(t)$ remains zero. For the usaul heat equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} v(x,t)= \Delta v(x,t),$ we have
$$\|v(t)\|_{L^2} \leq e^{-\lambda_1 t} \|v(0)\|_{L^2}.$$

**My question is the following:** Is there a similar  exponential decay estimate for this degenrate heat equation?

By the energy estimate, we have:
$$ \| u(x,t) \|_{L^{2}}^2 + 2 \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \left( \sin^2(\pi x_2) \Big(\frac{u}{ \partial x_{1}}(x,s) \Big)^2 + \sin^2(\pi x_1)  \Big(\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x_{2}}(x,s) \Big)^2  \right) dx \, d s \leq \| u(x,0) \|_{L^{2}}^2. $$
I tried to prove an inequality similar to Poincaré's inequality
$$ \| u(x,s) \|_{L^{2}}^2 \leq C \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \left( \sin^2(\pi x_2) \Big(\frac{u}{ \partial x_{1}}(x,s) \Big)^2 + \sin^2(\pi x_1)  \Big(\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x_{2}}(x,s) \Big)^2  \right) dx $$
If it is true, then quickly we can get the exponential decay $\|u(t)\|_{L^2} \leq e^{-C t} \|u(0)\|_{L^2}.$ But the closest result I can find is: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01054210. This is a one-dimensional result and seems difficult to scale to higher dimensions.

**Is there a way to get the above inequality or the decay rate of this degenerate heat equation? I would appreciate any helpful ideas or related literature.**

Comment: If $v(0)=1$ then $v(t)=1$ for every $t$ and does not decay. Do you have boundary conditions?

Comment: In fact, in your problem, $\lambda_1=0$, since constant function satisfies your equation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the condition $\int_{\mathbb{T}^2} u(x,0) \, d x=0$.

Comment: "*I tried to prove an inequality*" "*But the closest result I can find*" You do not prove elementary inequalities by literature search. You derive them from the first principles instead  :-) I'm too tired now to type anything substantial, but if I haven't made an idiotic mistake somewhere, then your version of Poincare bound holds and can be proved by first looking at circles around $0$ and then at rays deep inside the first quadrant. (I hope this information is enough for somebody more energetic than I to post a full solution before I return tomorrow)

Comment: @fedja I think I can prove Poincare assuming zero boundary conditions, since the quadratic form dominates the angular derivative. But I do not see how to do assuming zero mean, since this does not imply zero mean on each circle. Could you explain (or better post an answer)?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I posted an answer :-) I hope it makes sense. What remains mysterious to me, however, is what exactly happens at the origin: does the solution remain smooth there and, indeed, preserve the initial value, or it develops a singularity and then talking about $u(0)$ doesn't make much sense? Any ideas?

Comment: This degenerate heat equation comes from a special case of the stochastic model I studied. From the stochastic model,  I can assert that the solution is smooth at 0 when the initial value takes a particular form: $u_{0}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{T}^d} f(x+y)f(y) \, d y$, where $f(x)$ is a smooth function. Thanks for your answer, but I am sorry not to share the details of this stochastic model, as my research is still in its initial stages.

Answer (score 4):

OK, let me try :-) Consider the disk $D$ of radius $R=3/4$, say, around the origin. Note that $\sin^2\pi t$ and $t^2$ are comparable on $[-3/4,3/4]$, so I'll use just $x_1^2$ and $x_2^2$.

Let $E(x)^2=x_1^2u_{x_2}^2+x_2^2u_{x_1}^2$ in $D$. Now take a circle of radius $r<R$ and switch to polar coordinates. We have
$$
|u(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)_\theta|=|-r\sin\theta u_{x_1}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)
+r\cos\theta u_{x_2}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)|\le 2E(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\,.
$$
Thus, by the classical Poincare on the circle (or $[-\pi,\pi]$), we conclude that for every $r$, there exists $v(r)$ such that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi |u(re^{i\theta})-v(r)|^2\,d\theta\le C\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(re^{i\theta})^2\,d\theta\,.
$$
Integrating this against $rdr$ from $0$ to $R$, we conclude that
$$
\int_D |u-v|^2\le C\int_D E^2.
$$
Thus it remains to investigate the radial function $v$. Note that in the Poincare inequality on the circle, the quantity $v(r)$ can be taken to be the average of $u$ over any set of noticeable measure. I'll choose the interval $I=[\pi/6,\pi/3]$. If $\theta\in I$, then both $x_1,x_2$ are comparable to $r$, so $E(re^{i\theta})\approx r|\nabla u|$.
Hence the derivative $v_r(r)$ does not exceed $Cr^{-1}$ times the average of $E(re^{i\theta})$ over $\theta\in I$. Noticing that the square of the average does not exceed the average of the square, squaring, and integrating against $r\,dr$ again, we get
$$
\int_0^R r^3v_r(r)^2\,dr\le C\int_D E^2\,.
$$
What we want to control is $\int_0^R|v-v(R)|^2r\,dr$. Writing
$$
v(R)-v(r)=\int_r^R \frac{\rho v_r(\rho)}{\rho^2}\rho\,d\rho
$$
and
$$
\int_0^R r^3v_r(r)^2\,dr=\int_0^R (rv_r)^2 r\,dr
$$
we see that we just need to show that the operator $Tf(r)=\int_r^R \frac{f(\rho)}{\rho^2}\rho\,d\rho$ is bounded in $L^2((0,R), r\,dr)$. For that we'll just use the Schur test with $\psi(r)=r^{-1/2}$:
$$
\int_r^R\rho^{-2}\psi(\rho)\rho\,d\rho=
\int_r^R\rho^{-3/2}\,d\rho\le 2\le 2r^{-1/2}=2\psi(r)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\rho \frac 1{\rho^2}\psi(r)r\,dr=\int_0^\rho \frac 1{\rho^2}r^{1/2}\,dr=
\frac 23 \rho^{-1/2}=\frac 23\psi(\rho)
$$
and we are done.

Thus, there exists a constant $C(D)$ ($=v(R)$) such that $\int_D|u-C(D)|^2$ is controlled by $\int_D E^2$ and, thereby, by the integral in the desired Poincare inequality. However, $D$ covers the entire torus with some overlaps with itself, so, ignoring the overlaps, we conclude that $\int_{\mathbb T^2}|u-C(D)|^2$ is controlled. Since the mean of $u$ is $0$ and the mean is the best constant approximation of any function in $L^2$, we see that the integral of $|u|^2$ is controlled too and we are done.

I tried to spell all details out, but feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer; I checked and it works. To be sure I have understood, do you use only one circle to cover the Torus, using also the periodicity of the coefficients ($\sin (\pi x_i)$)? Concerning the regularity at $0$, I think that for continuous intial data, the solution is continuous for $t>0$ and preserves the value at $0$. However the existence of classical derivatives at $0$ is unclear to me.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune 1) Yes, just one disk. I actually started writing "the same estimates with possibly different constants hold for three other disks centered at $(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ and since they overlap, the constants must be close, etc.", but then I looked at it and got quite a bit perplexed because $(1,0)=(0,0)$ on the torus, so I finally realized that one disk is enough. 2) If there are no classical derivatives, there is no reason for the product $\sin^2x_1u_{x_2x_2}$ to be $0$ at $0$ and the value $u(0)$ may drift even with continuous $u$. So I wonder whether it happens :-)

Comment: The argument could be the following for $Lu=y^2 D_{xx}+x^2D_{yy}$ in the unit ball, with Neumann b.c.. Suppose $v_t-Lv=0, v(0)=f$. If $f$ is constant, then $v$ is constant, too. Then assume $f(0)=0$ or, by some density argument, $f\geq 0$ with support for $|x| \geq r$. Then $v$ is the limit of $v_s$ where $v_s-Lv_s=0, v_s(0)=f$ for $|x| \geq s$,  Neumann b.c for $|x|=1$ and Dirichlet for $|x|=s$. In the annulus of radii $s,r$ one has $v_s \leq u(t,x)=Ce^{2t}(x^2+y^2)$. In fact $u_t-Lu=0$ and $u$ is greater than $v_s$ on the parabolic boundary (choosing $C$).

Comment: Many points need a justification,  in particular the convergence of $v_s$. Also the origin is not the only singularity and some other care is necessary to have a real proof.